# A better way to search for tags in mysql table

Tags: mysql, tags

Say I have a table and one of the columns is titled tags with data that is comma separated like this.

```
"tag1,tag2,new york,tag4"
```

As you can see, some of tags will have spaces.

Whats the best or most accurate way of querying the table for any tags that are equal to "new york"?

In the past I've used:

```
SELECT id WHERE find_in_set('new york',tags) <> 0
```

But find_in_set does not work when the value has a space.

I'm currently using this:

```
SELECT id WHERE concat(',',tags,',') LIKE concat(',%new york%,')
```

But I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

How would you do it?

Comment: the problem in 2nd approach is what if you have tags like `tag1` and `tag10`, both returns true if you search for the `tag1`.

Comment: Well, yes - that's one problem for sure.

Comment: Exactly, not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Nomalization is not an option at this point.  I did not design the database, nor can it be redesigned. All I can do is query it...

Comment: Clear violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of proper [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Don't do this. If you're stuck with this schema you're in for a world of hurt because relational databases really do not like comma separated values. The performance of any query will be somewhere be brutally slow and this will probably melt and destroy any server hardware you throw at it if you're dealing with non-trivial amounts of data.

Comment: Normalize the data. People always say they can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Item A can be associated with many of item B, and item B can be associated with many of item A. This is called [Many to many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))

Data with these relationship should be stored in separate table and join together only on query.

Examble

Table 1

```
| product_uid | price | amount |
|      1      | 12000 |  3000  |
|      2      | 30000 |   600  |
```

Table 2

```
| tag_uid | tag_value |
|    1    |   tag_01  |
|    2    |   tag_02  |
|    3    |   tag_03  |
|    4    |   tag_04  |
```

Then we use a join table to relate them

Table 3

```
| entry_uid | product_uid | tag_uid |
|    1      |     1       |     3   |
|    2      |     1       |     4   |
|    3      |     2       |     1   |
|    4      |     2       |     2   |
|    5      |     4       |     2   |
```

The query will be (If you want to select item one and the tag)

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.tag_value 
FROM Table1 as t1,
JOIN Table3 as join_table ON t1.product_uid = join_table.product_uid
JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t2.tag_uid = join_table.tag_uid
WHERE t1.product_uid = 1
```

Comment: From experience, this works fine on small data-set, but having join on large data-set really can get the DB to it's knee. Is it really the most efficient method ?

Comment: If you normalize your database (normalization means the method I used above), it will take slightly longer time to select from table, but it will only take one entry to update the record. If you do not normalize the database, select will be a bit faster, but you will need to update multiple entry when updating the table. There are cases where not normalizing database make sense, for example log or transaction history, but most of the time I would wager it is better then dealing with data inconsistency. To read more: https://www.thoughtco.com/should-i-normalize-my-database-1019730

Answer (score 2):

If I needed to ignore the leading spaces before and after the commas in `tags`.

For example, if `tags` had a value of:

```
'atlanta,boston , chicago, los angeles  , new york '
```

and assuming spaces are the only character I want to ignore, and the tag I'm searching for doesn't have any leading or trailing spaces, then I'd likely use a regular expression. Something like this:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM t
 WHERE t.tags REGEXP CONCAT('^|, *', 'new york' ,' *,|$')
```

---

I recommend Bill Karwin's excellent book "SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming"

[https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)

Chapter 2 Jaywalking covers the antipattern of comma separated lists.