# MySQL query pivot where all options exist

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table `entries` with a primary key `id`. Also I have a pivot table `entries_tags` with foreign keys `entry_id` and `tag`. `tag` is plain text by the way, I know this should be normalized but that is not an option. Right now I have built a query to retrieve all entries by one specific tag.

I want to run a query (as efficient as possible) where I would retrieve entries having all of the tags I specify.

In case it helps this is the current query where I retrieve all entries by one specific tag:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM entries
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT entry_id
   FROM entries_tags
   WHERE tag = '...'
)
```

#### Example

Example data

`entries`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | entry 1 |
| 2 | entry 2 |
| 3 | entry 3 |

`entries_tags`

| entry_id | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | C |

Expected result
In *matching entries* I expect the complete line, here I note only the ids for ease of reading.

Notes

- The order of the tags provided should not be taken into consideration.
- The order of the results is not of interest.

| input tags | matching entries |
| --- | --- |
| `A` `B` | `1` `2` |
| `A` `C` | `1` `3` |
| `A` `B` `C` | `1` |
| `A` | `1` `2` `3` `4` |

Thank you for your time

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired result - HTH ;)

Comment: What about *input tags=`B` `A`*? is input tags always sorted?

Comment: can [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39239521/4519059) help?

Comment: @shA.t It is different because in that question he searches by a single tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the simplest method but not necessarily the most performant:

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM entries e
JOIN entries_tags et ON e.id = et.entry_id
WHERE et.tag IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY et.entry_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3; -- because you are looking for three tags
```

You need a composite index on `entries_tags (entry_id, tag)`, preferably unique. If not unique, you need to change the `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT et.tag)`.

If your `entries` rows are very large, running the aggregation in a subquery may be faster:

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM (
    SELECT entry_id
    FROM entries_tags
    WHERE tag IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
    GROUP BY entry_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
) et
JOIN entries e ON e.id = et.entry_id;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IZXOfC7C).

---

While playing with a test dataset (~1M entries, ~4M entries_tags and 4K distinct tags) I was very surprised by some of the results I saw. You may not see similar behaviour but I thought it worth noting.

In many test cases the following query was much faster:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM entries e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM entries_tags WHERE entry_id = e.id AND tag = 'A')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM entries_tags WHERE entry_id = e.id AND tag = 'B')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM entries_tags WHERE entry_id = e.id AND tag = 'C');
```

Comment: I was just about to post my similar solution `SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id IN (<that select query you wrote>)` which one of these two do you think it will perform better with 40~ million entries and thousands of tags? BTW you can omit the `distinct` because the tags per entry are indeed unique.

Comment: It will depend on the rest of the query, MySQL version, table structure, indices and data distribution. Presumably you have sorting and pagination, which will add significantly to the overhead.

Comment: I think I got that index the wrong way around, although you almost certainly need both. Have PK in one direction and secondary in the other - `PK (tag, entry_id)` and `INDEX (entry_id, tag)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INTERSECT` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM entries
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT entry_id
   FROM entries_tags
   WHERE tag = 'tag1'
)
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM entries
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT entry_id
   FROM entries_tags
   WHERE tag = 'tag2'
)
-- Add more INTERSECT for additional tags if needed
;
```

It gets less sufficient with the tags number growth.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your input tags are single-space separated value like `A B` or `A B C` and space not allowed in tag names.
in this case you can use a query like this:

```sql
select e.id
from entries e
  left join entries_tags et
  on e.id = et.entry_id
group by e.id
having sum(case when 'A B' like concat('%',et.tag,'%') then 1 else 0 end) = 
  length('A B')-length(replace('A B',' ',''))+1
```

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ae3ec/12)</kbd>

In having part I find tags by `like` operator and sum all founded tags.
then I need to calculate count of tags, so i use a little hack by removing single-spaces to find it, the result will be `entries.id`s that have all similar tags.

> Note: using name of tags in queries is a bad-practice, I suggest you to use another table to store tags with ids and use those ids in middle table.
> actually in queries like my approach similarity will not work properly for some similar tags, I can improve my query a bit to cover some cases.

An improvement can be like this: `concat(' ','A B',' ') like concat('% ',et.tag,' %')`; so query should be like:

```sql
select e.id
from entries e
  left join entries_tags et
  on e.id = et.entry_id
group by e.id
having sum(case when concat(' ','A B',' ') like concat('% ', et.tag, ' %') then 1 else 0 end) = 
  length('A B')-length(replace('A B',' ',''))+1
```

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ae3ec/14)</kbd>

With adding variable to query you can test easily like this:
<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ae3ec/17)</kbd>